# Wordpress htaccess redirect issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a few pages to different pages. This should be simple, but I'm missing something simple, apparently.

I have a wordpress install on a subdomain. Wordpress's generic htaccess is this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I want to redirect `/farm-partners/` to `/farm-partners/emilys-produce/`. I'm trying to do so using the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^farm-partners/?$ /farm-partners/emilys-produce/ [L]
```

However, opening `/farm-partners/` doesn't redirect, it just loads that page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the  [WordPress Redirect plugin](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/) and don't mess with the htaccess.

What you are missing in your RewriteRule though, it telling it that you want an external redirect

```
RewriteRule ^farm-partners/?$ /farm-partners/emilys-produce/ [L,R=301]
```

If you use a `RewriteRule`, make sure it is outside the comments that indicate which parts of the file may be edited without any notice (i.e. outside the #comments marking WordPress's section of the file. Similarly if you are using W3 Total Cache or a similar plugin.)

Comment: Using the WordPress Redirect plugin was the first line of my suggestion. The rest was informational, in case in the future you do not have a plugin available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule farm-partners/$ /farm-partners/emilys-produce/
```

Comment: in retrospect, i agree with yakatz's answer. Using 301s after letting WP monkey with your urls already could cause some weird results.  My code above should work, but the plug-in would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Your RewriteRule does not change anything (at least in my tests). To get the RewriteEngine to do an external redirect, you need to put a URL which requires that (i.e. on another site) and no Proxy flag, or a Redirect flag (with the 301 status code meaning permanent redirect, since the default is 302 temporary.)